# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function with useEffect React with latest version

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using react for 1st time below is my code for studentlist.js and App.js

```
import { useTable, useEffect } from "react-table";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function StudentList() {
  const [data, setStudentData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {console.log("hi")})

  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "First",
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Last",
        accessor: "lastName"
      },
      {
        Header: "DOB",
        accessor: "dateOfBirth"
      },
      {
        Header: "Phone",
        accessor: "studentPhone"
      },
      {
        Header: "Price €",
        accessor: "price"
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({ columns, data });

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()} style={{ border: "solid 1px blue" }}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th
                {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                style={{
                  borderBottom: "solid 3px red",
                  background: "aliceblue",
                  color: "black",
                  fontWeight: "bold"
                }}
              >
                {column.render("Header")}
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map(row => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return (
                  <td
                    {...cell.getCellProps()}
                    style={{
                      padding: "10px",
                      border: "solid 1px gray",
                      background: "papayawhip"
                    }}
                  >
                    {cell.render("Cell")}
                  </td>
                );
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

export default StudentList;
```

For App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import StudentList from "./components/studentlist";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
            <StudentList></StudentList>
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My package dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "npm": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.4",
    "react-table": "^7.6.0"
  }
```

I am facing this error

**TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
StudentList
src/components/studentlist.js:9**

I have tried the below option

npm install
npm fix

If i remove useEffect i can see empty table rendered. But with useEffect is see a problem

Comment: `useEffect`should be imported from `react`, not `react-table`. `import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";`

Comment: `import React, { useState , useEffect } from 'react';`

Comment: thanks for pointing it out i totally missed it